# Like a Spoonerism but within one word

Tags: errors

Spoonerism is the transposition of sounds or morphemes across two words. Think "Pheasant Plucker"

But is there a name for doing a similar thing within a word. E.g. 'north' for 'thorn'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Metathesis**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis_(linguistics)): "Metathesis  is the transposition of sounds or syllables in a word or of words in a sentence."

It commonly but not always occurs between adjacent sounds. They give examples such as the confusion of "asterisk" and "Asterix" (comic book character) and the pronunciation of "comfortable" as /ˈkʌmftərbəl/. Wikipedia also mentions turning "spaghetti" into "pasketti", which is a fairly common nickname/jokey term for the pasta (although here the /g/ becomes devoiced).

Comment: Stress on the second syllable, maTATHussus. Automnemonic for _Metathesis_ is _Methatesis_.

Comment: Pasketti is the perfect example, thank you!
Shame it's not as nice a word as Spoonerism, though! Not so easy to throw in to a conversation!